# Unable to install ownCloud-Desktop-Client

Tags: applications

I'm starting to work with elementary OS since a while and I like it very much! Thanks guys!

I have the last version installed:

```
...@eOS:~$ uname -a
Linux eOS 3.19.0-42-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 18 10:25:23 UTC 2015 i686 athlon i686 GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying now to install ownCloud-Client but get some dependency errors:

```
...@eOS:~$ sudo apt-get install owncloud-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  owncloud-client : Depends: libowncloudsync0 (= 2.1.0-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
               Depends: owncloud-client-l10n but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please [edit] and output of `apt-cache policy owncloud-client   owncloud-client:i386 libowncloudsync0 libstdc++6 owncloud-client-l10n`

Comment: I met exactly the same problems and the answer about clearing up and fixing apt-get didn't help. Is there any other way than to reinstall the OS?

Comment: I have the same problem, but these commands didn't help for me. Still the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

Enter these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Try to fix the broken dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And enter again `sudo apt-get -f install`.

This should solve your dependency problems and you can now install `owncloud-client` again.

Answer (score 1):

For Loki:

> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/owncloud-client.list"
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install owncloud-client
> ```